# Makefile explanation. Understanding someone else's Makefile

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, compilation, makefile, g++

I am relatively new to programming on Linux.

I understand that Makefiles are used to ease the compiling process when compiling several files. 
Rather than writing "g++ main.cpp x.cpp y.cpp -o executable" everytime you need to compile and run your program, you can throw it into a Makefile and run make in that directory.

I am trying to get a RPi and Arduino to communicate with each other using the nRF24L01 radios using tmrh20's library [here.](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24) I have been successful using tmrh20's Makefile to build the the executable needed (on the RPi). I would like to, however, use tmrh20's library to build my own executables.

I have watched several tutorial videos on Makefiles but still cannot seem to piece together what is happening in tmrh20's.

The Makefile (1) in question is [here.](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples_linux/Makefile.examples)  I believe it is somehow referencing a second Makefile (2) (for filenames?) [here.](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/examples_linux/Makefile) (Why is this necessary?)

If it helps anyone understand (it took me a while) I had to build using SPIDEV (the instructions [here](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html)) the Makefile (3) in the RF24 directory which produced several object files which I think are relevant to Makefile (1)&(2).

How do I find out what files I need to make my own Makefile, from tmrh20's Makefile (if that makes sense?) He seems to use variables in his Makefile that are not defined? Or are perhaps defined elsewhere?

Apologies for my poor explanation.

Comment: I suspect, this question might be a better fit for StackOverflow?

Comment: This is far too broad a question for SO in my opinion.  I don't have time to figure out the entire build environment for this tool, but I will say that it's not the case that Makefile.example (Makefile 1) references Makefile (Makefile 2).  It's the other way around.  Makefile contains `include Makefile.examples` and so that's what it does.  To understand make and Makefiles you might investigate: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The canonical sequence is not just `make` and `make install`. There is an initial `./configure` step (such a file is [here](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/configure)) that sets up everything and generates several files used in the `make` steps.

You only need to run this `configure` script successfully only once, unless you want to change build parameters. I say "successfully" because the first execution will usually complain that you are missing libraries or header files. But ince `./configure` runs without errors, `make` and `make install` should run without errors.

PS: I didn't try to compile it, but since the project has a rather comprehensive `configure` it is likely complete and you shouldn't need to tweak makefiles if your follow the usual procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for splitting the Makefiles in the way you've mentioned and linked to here is to separate the definition of the variables from the implementation. This way you could have multiple base Makefiles that define their `PROGRAM` variable differently, but all do the same thing based on the value of that variable.

In my own personal opinion, I see some value here - but there very many ways to skin this proverbial cat.

Having learned GNU Make the hard way, I can only recommend you do the same. There's a slight steep curve at the beginning, but once you get the main concepts down following other peoples Makefiles gets pretty easy.

Good luck: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html